# Python Pytube progress for playlist download

Tags: python, pytube

I am writing a program in python using pytube, and I want to indicate progress when downloading a playlist. When downloading a single video I can do:

```
YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progressFunction)
```

but that doesn't work when downloading a playlist:

```
Playlist(url, on_progress_callback=progressFunction)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_progress_callback'
```

Is there any way to get the progress when downloading a playlist?

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can get all the urls from the Playlist and then call download one by one.
this works for me all the best.

```
def getAllLinks(playList):
'''
: This function take a link of playlist and return the link of each videos
:param playList:
:return: A list of all Url links
'''
allLinks = []
youtubeLink = 'https://www.youtube.com'
pl = Playlist(playList)
for linkprefix in pl.parse_links():
    allLinks.append(youtubeLink + linkprefix)
return allLinks
```

from this you will get all the urls and then

```
def downloadPlaylist(playlistLink):
linkArray = getAllLinks(playlistLink)
for link in linkArray:
    downloadVideo(link)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/contrib/playlist.py), the `Playlist` class doesn't need  `on_progress_callback` keyword argument, but only the `url` one.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: I mean, pytube does not provide this functionality, but you can easily adding it by forking the project, modifying the code and (why not) making a PR.

Comment: Thanks for the question posted, I only figured it out after an hour and below is my answer.
Let me know if it worked out for you as well @MátéVarga

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [register_on_progress_callback](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=progress#pytube.YouTube.register_on_progress_callback) function to register a download progress callback function post initialization.

An example of this would be:

```
p = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLetg744TF10BrdPjaEXf4EsJ1wz6fyf95')
for v in p.videos:
    v.register_on_progress_callback(progressFunction)
    # proceed to downloading...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube.cli import on_progress

yt_playlist = Playlist(url)
for video in yt_playlist.videos:
    video.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
    video.streams.first().download()
```